# Excel formula that can produce a date range that falls between two other date ranges?

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, range

I need a formula that can produce a date range that falls between two other date ranges. If date ranges A and B are provided, the overlapping date range C captures dates that exist in both range a and range B. Is there a formula I can write to produce this operation? Thank you.

[image]

I am not sure how to solve this with a formula.

Comment: From your examples it seems you are looking for the largest interval that contains both A & B everywhere,  right?

Comment: Please explain what the "correct" output of your example would be, what it would be based upon, and where would it appear.

Answer (score 2):

It's not perfectly clear what you're trying to achieve. But it seems like maybe you're just trying to find the `MAX` of the start dates and the `MIN` of the end dates.

So to find the MAX start date:

```
=MAX(A2,D2)
```

And to find the MIN end date:

```
=MIN(B2,E2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This formula spills the result and returns an error message if there isn't an overlap of the ranges.

=LET(rangeA,SEQUENCE(B2-A2+1,,A2,1),rangeB,SEQUENCE(E2-D2+1,,D2,1),range,FILTER(rangeA,DROP(REDUCE("",rangeA,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(y,rangeB))))),1)),
startC,TAKE(range,1),endC,TAKE(range,-1),IFERROR(HSTACK(startC,endC),"no overlapping date range"))

[image: Excel formula that can produce a date range that falls between two other date ranges?]